# Session getting null on some pages in node.js and express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

I am using express in node.js and trying to set the session variable here is my code:-

```
var express = require('express');
app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret', cookie: { maxAge: 999999999, path: '/' } })); // session secret
```

Here m setting session:-

```
 app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
   req.session.Name="Hello";
 }
```

its working fine and return value for these routes:-

```
app.get('/users',function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.Name);
    res.render('home.ejs');
});
app.get('/userList',function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.Name);
    res.render('home.ejs');
});
```

But not working in this route and always return undefined or null:-

```
 app.get('/user/:id', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.Name);
    res.render('home.ejs');
});
```

what I am doing wrong?
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be you use an outdated version of packages. Same code is work with package express-session. (https://github.com/expressjs/session). 
Example code is below:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var app = express();
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'mysecret',
        cookie: {
            maxAge: 999999999,
            path: '/'
        }
    })); // session secret
    app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
        req.session.Name = "Hello";
        res.send('Hello World');
    });
    app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.session.Name);
        res.send('Hello World');
    });
    app.get('/userList', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.session.Name);
        res.send('Hello World');
    });
    app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.session.Name);
        res.send('Hello World');
    });
    app.listen(8080);
```